# Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-manifest

I know that there are two ways to let your program know about a broadcast receiver. You can either specify in the manifest file or you can dynamically register it in the java files. I know if you put it in the java files then you must unregister it also. My question is if you specify it only in the manifest file is there anywhere you have to specifically unregister it. Maybe in the manifest file? Maybe in the java file? Or perhaps if declared in manifest file you never have to unregister it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auwall,

As stated in the Documentation:

> Base class for code that will receive
>   intents sent by sendBroadcast(). You
>   can either dynamically register an
>   instance of this class with
>   Context.registerReceiver() or
>   statically publish an implementation
>   through the  tag in your
>   AndroidManifest.xml. Note:    If
>   registering a receiver in your
>   Activity.onResume() implementation,
>   you should unregister it in
>   Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive
>   intents when paused, and this will cut
>   down on unnecessary system overhead).
>   Do not unregister in
>   Activity.onSaveInstanceState(),
>   because this won't be called if the
>   user moves back in the history stack

The note about unregistering the `BroadcastReceiver` only applies to when you register it programatically in `onResume()`.  You will not need to unregister if you registered it in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Can you answer why when I do it statically in the manifest file and i close the program with finish() do the broadcast receivers still listen and do what i told them to do? What i'm saying is the receivers seem to never turn off even after the app finishes. If you need code i can provide it when i get home this afternoon. Thanks

Comment: Why do they continue to listen if registered in the manifest? Because that's what they were made to do.  If you don't want that to happen you'd want to register/unregister programmatically.

Comment: Ok well I was under the impression if declared if in the manifest file then the program just unregistered it for you when you the app was done. I wasn't sure so I was just trying to see which route I needed to go. I now get it. If in the manifest file it stays registered and if you want it to do start and stop then you need to do it in the program itself. Thanks for the help